# How to calculate or estimate the probability of a sum of Bernouillis being less than a value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $X = (x_1,...,x_n)$ be a vector, where each $x_i$ is either $1$ or $0$, with probability $p_i$.

What is $\displaystyle P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i<\alpha\right)$ for some certain value $\alpha$?

In other words, if for instance $\alpha = 2$, we first need to calculate the probability that all $x_i$ are $0$, then the probability to have one $1$ somewhere. Then, we need to calculate the probability that the first one is equal to $1$, the second is equal to $1$ and then all the other guys are $0$. Then the probability that the first one is $1$ the second one $0$ and the third one = $1$, and all the other $0$ and so on...
​
However, this takes too much time to compute by doing so. If we imagine $n= 10000$ and $\alpha = 500$, it will already take a huge amount of time.

Therefore my question is : Is there a possibility to calculate or approximate that quickly ? What is the error of the approximation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say - use the binomial probability distribution, (and central limit theorem).

Comment: What would be the parameter p ? an average of the p_i I have ?

Comment: Do you have any prior on $p_i$?

Comment: My p_i are all very small. Should I draw a histogram? What does it change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $N$ is atleast 50 then you could use a gaussian approximation:

$$
\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i
$$
$$
\sigma^2=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i(1-p_i)
$$
Then the probability of a sum less than $\alpha$ is:
$$
P= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{z_s} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}} dz
$$
where 
$$
z_s=\frac{\alpha-\bar x}{\sigma}
$$

Comment: Does this also mean that it is independent of the distribution of the pi ?